# Extracting a vector from a struct

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-struct

I got a struct after using `dir(directoryName)`. I want to get a vector containing all the file names in that folder.

- How do I extract a vector of names from the struct?
- Is there a better way to get a vector with the names of all files in a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```
dirData = dir(directoryName);
fileNames = {dirData(~[dirData.isdir]).name};
```

This works by making use of [comma-separated lists](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). When you have a structure array and you index a field with the dot operator, you get a comma-separated list of values that you can then pass to a function or collect with square or curly brackets. This code:

```
...[dirData.isdir]...
```

Collects the `isdir` field from every structure in the array, putting the values in a vector using square brackets so it can be used as a logical index. Then this code:

```
... {dirData(...).name};
```

Collects the `name` field from every structure in the array, putting the strings in a cell array.